# jquery latest conflict, having difficulty troubleshooting

Tags: jquery

Hello All and thanks ahead for any help

I'm working on a website which references a global template that calls jquery-latest-min.js

So before you ask, the version will change beyond my control.

After many hours of troubleshooting some jquery code, I've found that  removing the call for jquery latest will make the code work again, however when it's broken, the following code doesn't return the correct option index. If you remove jquery latest, it works.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest-min.js"></script> <!-- THIS IS THE ONE CAUSING CONFLICT -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("div.click").click(function(){
            selectedOptionIndex = $("#mySelect option:selected").index();
            alert(selectedOptionIndex); // should alert "0"
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="">0</option>
        <option value="">1</option>
        <option value="">2</option>
        <option value="">3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="click">
        Click
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is there a problem with jquery latest? The version in particular here is v1.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're including two versions of jQuery, that's probbaly causing the conflicts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest-min.js"></script>
```

You only need one. So try removing the jquery-1.4.4.min.js.

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, I think it actually has to do with the very old version of latest, I'm going to have them address this. Using only one version only worked if it was the 1.4.4, using latest alone didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @xiatica - Okay, that makes sense. You could check the source of jquery-latest-min.js which should have a commented line in it of what version it is.